# How do i stop part of a method being called?

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm pretty new to coding and I'm creating a quiz using C#, however i'm running into problems when trying to increment the total score when an answer is answered correctly.  the code calling the method is:

```
    private void nextQuestionButton1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (majNugentRadioButton.Checked)
        {
            // increment total score
            Program.Score();
            // load question 2
            Question2 win2 = new Question2();
            win2.Show();
            this.Close();
        }
        else
        {
            // load question 2
            Question2 win2 = new Question2();
            win2.Show();
            this.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

And the code for the Program.Score(); method is:

```
    static public void Score()
    {
        int totalScore = 0;
        totalScore++;
    }
```

When i call this method from the 2nd question it sets the totalScore back to 0, how can i get it so that it only assigns the value of 0 the first time it's called?

Comment: `totalScore` is locally scoped to the `Score()` method which means it only exists within this method. Basically it creates a new variable, assignes it a value of 0, increments it by one, then discards the variable.

Comment: Declare you totalScore variable as static

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your score method is in your program class, you should create a static TotalScore in program class:

```
public static class Program
{
    private static int TotalScore;

    static public void Score()
    {
        TotalScore++;
    }
    //... Other stuff
}
```

In your implementation it's obvious that every time you call Program.Score(), the local variable in Score method setts to 0 and then ++

**Important:**

Remember that static methods can only access static members, so you should declare TotalScore as static.

Comment: Thank you Reza, i knew it would be something simple.

Answer (score 1):

Every time you call the method Score() you are creating a new variable called totalScore and assigning it a value of 0

to solve this declare the totalScore variable outside the scope of the Score() method so it is not assigned the value of 0 every time you call Score()

```
int totalScore = 0;

static public void Score()
{
    totalScore++;
}
```

Comment: My mistake... missed it was static

Answer (score 0):

Declare your **TotalScore** variable outside the **Score()** method. If you declare inside the method, when it has been called,the value of TotalScore assigned as 0.

Then Declare the **TotalScore** as *static variable*. Because inside the static method, you can access only static members.